# How turn off Elastic search on Magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch, magento2.4.5

I try to turn off Elasticsearch to use Algolia Search as the default search engine. I try this command line:

```
bin/magento module:disable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}
```

But when I access category pages, it show this bug:

```
[2022-12-26T07:02:50.729178+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Missing required argument $adapters of Magento\Search\Model\AdapterFactory. [] []
[2022-12-26T07:02:50.820437+00:00] main.CRITICAL: BadMethodCallException: Missing required argument $adapters of Magento\Search\Model\AdapterFactory. in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:264
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Magento\\Search\\...', Array, Array)
#1 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Search\\...', Array, Array)
#2 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Search\\...', Array, Array)
#3 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Search\\...')
#4 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Search\\...')
#5 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Search\\...', NULL, 'adapterFactory', 'Magento\\Search\\...')
#6 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Magento\\Search\\...', Array, Array)
#7 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Search\\...', Array, Array)
#8 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Search\\...', Array, Array)
#9 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Search\\...')
#10 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Search\\...')
#11 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'searchEngine', 'Magento\\Search\\...')
#12 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Magento\\Search\\...', Array, Array)
#13 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Search\\...', Array, Array)
#14 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Search\\...', Array, Array)
```

Anybody has any idea, please let me know. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algolia is intend to replace Magento default **Search**, not affect catalog product listing in both backend and frontend which use Elastichsearch.

So you should keep Elastichsearch modules for catalog product listing.

---

**Updated based on additional information from the original poster**
In case you don't want to use or are not ready to use Elasticsearch engine, you can use this module to disable Elasticsearch: https://github.com/zepgram/module-disable-search-engine

Comment: Thank you! I don't use Elasticsearch and I don't have Elasticsearch engine on my server.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your new information.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Please restart the elastic search service and run the magento commands

sudo service elasticsearch restart if this running correctly, 
then check your module php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch7

Still not worked, try below,

put params of working ElasticSearch service in Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search 
PLease have look into this as well,

https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-replace-magento2-default-search-engine/

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! I don't use Elasticsearch and I don't have Elasticsearch engine on my server.